# Uploading CSV/Excel data, present mapping functionality or download the schema?

Tags: data-mapping

With this question assume the users understand CSV/Excel.

I am looking for the most usable approach for importing data (5-15 rows) into an application.

1. Is it better to let the users download an Excel/CSV template, populate then upload?

   **or**
2. Is it better to let the users upload whatever Excel/CSV they have and allow mapping functionality?

   **or**
3. Tell me a better way.

My thoughts are they you usually give the users some-kind of confirmation on what to import, so why not just go ahead with the mapping functionality and kill two birds with one stone?

Comment: I've never seen #1 before. Great idea.

Comment: We use #1 at our company almost exclusively. We combine our imports with exports that follow the same layout. the idea being a user can download their data into an xls, edit it, then re-import it. Works at treat.
We also have error checking for mis-matched columns

Comment: A related question about [interface for mapping the fields](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/optimal-interface-for-specifying-a-mapping-between-known-field-set-and-fields-dis), if option #2 is chosen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could tell them what columns are expected and have a button to download a blank file for convenience (#1) or let them create / use their own file.

Once the file is uploaded, if the column names don't already match, you could provide the [mapping functionality](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/optimal-interface-for-specifying-a-mapping-between-known-field-set-and-fields-dis) (#2).

An experienced user might already have the file with the right column names and could skip both steps.

Comment: I like the idea of checking to see if the columns match and then presenting them with an error and a mapping ui when they don't already match.

Comment: It is a really good question. Is there yet a better way to solve this, I wonder?

Answer (score 3):

I actually have this exact problem on the app I design.  Header mapping never made it into the roadmap so users are forced to fix the headers in Excel.  We give them a template, but users still get really annoyed.  They often get lists from 3rd party sources and having to do the fixup is a pain.

I wish I had escalated the header-mapping UI a long time ago.  I am still trying to get it on the roadmap.

Currently, we give good feedback on the columns that DO match properly and the ones that don't, but it's not ideal.